# Can anyone explain how line 3 follows from line 2?

Tags: probability-theory, density-function, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Can anyone explain how line 3 follows from line 2? IDK how Fubini's works with improper integrals. I just know that $\displaystyle\int_a^b\int_c^d g(x,y)\,dx,\,dy = \int_c^d\int_a^b g(x,y)\,dy\,dx$ holds for non-neg functions (which the PDF below is) but IDK how that allows the inner integral to start at $t$.

[image: tail sum]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a matter of recognising that
$$
\{(x,t): x\ge 0 \wedge 0 \leq t \leq x\}=\{(x,t): t \ge 0 \wedge x \ge t\}
$$

Just sketch the two sets and you'll see... This is why you have that
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} \int_0^x g(x,t) \, dt dx = \int_0^{+\infty} \int_t^{+\infty} g(x,t) \, dx dt. 
$$

Comment: I think the $x\geq t$ constraint helps.  But am not sure how to sketch $t$...

Comment: @JohnD Then skip the sketching and just observe that $t\leq x$ if and only if $x\geq t$.